# StorageClientException On Blob.UploadAsync methods

Tags: asynchronous, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have implemented following async blob upload method to upload multiple blocks.

```
        var container = GetContainer(containerName);

        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

        String[] base64EncodedBlockIds = new String[10];// 10- number of Blocks

        //To upload the blocks in parallel - 10 parallel blocks
        ParallelLoopResult parallelLoopResult = Parallel.For(0,10, i =>
            {
                String base64EncodedBlockId = Convert.ToBase64String(System.BitConverter.GetBytes(i));                                 
                byte[] bytesMemoryStream = GetBytesFromStream(stream);
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytesMemoryStream))
                {
                    blob.PutBlock(base64EncodedBlockId, memoryStream, null);// throws an exception "The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format"

                }
                base64EncodedBlockIds[i] = base64EncodedBlockId;
            });
        blob.PutBlockList(base64EncodedBlockIds);
```

It throws an exception "The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format".

Need your inputs

Regards,
Vivek

Comment: Can you check the fiddler trace to identify for which Put Block request you're getting an error. That should tell you the headers sent with each request as well.

Comment: @Vivek - I see that you just un-accepted my answer. What did the problem turn out to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BlockIDs within a blob must all be the same length (number of characters). BlockID "10" is longer than the others, which is probably the source of your problem.

One solution would be to zero-pad the BlockIDs to the same length.

Answer (score 1):

In my case "The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format" error occurred because I was trying to write an empty block (`memoryStream` had 0 bytes). PutBlock failed beause the content length was 0 in the header.